# Unable to use a js file in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, three.js

I'm trying to use Three.js in an Angular app.

To import Three, i just followed the [doc](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/OBJLoader2).
So I have this : `import * as THREE from 'three';`

I also did `npm install @types/three --save`.

The problem comes when I try to use my models using [OBJLoader2](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/OBJLoader2)

Firstly, the doc says to use `var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader2();`.
But actually, THREE.OBJLoader2 is not defined in `'three'`, it is defined in `three/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader2.js`, as i found in [the official example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj2.html).

So, I tryed to import this file in many several ways, but i'm not able to get it work.
I naively tryed to imported the file this way :
`import ../../node_modules/three/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader2.js';`
It is compiling but I have this error in the navigator

> OBJLoader2.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined
>       at eval (OBJLoader2.js:8)
>       at Object.../../../../three/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader2.js (vendor.bundle.js:430)

The file looks like this :

```
'use strict';
if ( THREE.OBJLoader2 === undefined ) { THREE.OBJLoader2 = {} }
THREE.OBJLoader2 = (function () { ... })()
```

It exepts THREE to be defined globaly, but TREE only exists in my component, so i understand the error.

Before importing the file, I also tryed to declare THREE :

```
declare var THREE;
```

or

```
declare global{
  interface Window{THREE:any;}
}
import * as THREE from 'three';
window.THREE = THREE;
```

The last code made the error disappear, but when I try to use the loader

```
var loader = THREE.OBJLoader2();
loader.load('assets/untitled1.obj', callbackOnLoad, null, null, null, false);
```

I got this :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined
>       at AppComponent.initCube (app.component.ts:52)

So I'm stuck here, I can't find anything on the internet, to believe that nobody ever tried to import models using three.js in Typescript.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Try adding three into a script tag within your `index.html` file, or within the scripts array of `angular-cli.json`

Comment: When i import scripts in .angular-cli.json
> THREE.OBJLoader2 is not a constructor

When i add thoses scripts in index.html (plus three.min.js), the variable THREE is not defined in my component, even when i do "declare var THREE;" and "this.THREE = THREE" in constructor.

Comment: Please explain why downvote. There is no working solution on the net, the explication of my problem is detailed and I looked for a solution by myself...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but it looks like there's a solution at https://bountify.co/angular-cli-three-js-blank-project-using-typescript-3

I believe that the salient points are:

1. npm install three --save
2. npm install @types/three --save-dev
3. import * as THREE from 'three'

It sounds like you are already doing #1 and #2

Comment: This code is ok but it does not use features that cause me problems